# Trying to use notification inboxStyle to show more lines similar to GMAIL app in notification but it doesn't work

Tags: android, notifications, gmail, notificationmanager

This is the code that I have:

```
  NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new Notification.InboxStyle();
    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Title - Notification");
    inboxStyle.setSummaryText("TEST");
    inboxStyle.addLine("LINE");
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(getActivity())
            .setContentTitle("PSNGR")
            .setContentText("PITSTOP BLA").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setContentIntent(null).build();

    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notifManager.notify(0, noti);
```

But nothing from the InboxStyle notification works. I only get PSNGR and PITSTOP BLA, why is that?

PS: Also tried with BitTextStyle() but also nothing is seen:
For this code:

```
 NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity())
            .setContentTitle("PSNGR")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("MATA"))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("MATA2"))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(null);
    notifManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

I only see: "PSNGR"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used RemoteViews instead of the normal notification:

```
 NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity()).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    RemoteViews mContentView = new RemoteViews(getActivity().getPackageName(), R.layout.pitstop_notification);
    mContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.notification_icon);
    mContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Custom notification");
    mContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "This is a custom layout");
    mContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text2, "This is a custom layout2");
    mBuilder.setContent(mContentView);
    notifManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```